# UK Visitor Visa application NY decision delayed

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, new-york-city, delays

I was one of the applicants affected by the temporary refusal of UKVI to accept biometrics at the USCIS locations. I ended doing my biometrics month after I applied online and it has been **4 weeks** now since I sent them the paperwork (UK Visa website still claims 99% of family visits visas are processed in 15 days).

I called the paid assistance line a week ago and they said they have **"escalated"** my application (which means a guaranteed decision in  15 more days) so it would get looked at sooner. They also said they will work around my travel dates (my original travel date was May 25th but now I have pushed it to June 1st) which does not seem to be the case. My application is pretty straightforward and I have been to the UK 3 times on a visit visa before.

1. Has anyone any insight into what this verbal escalation means?
2. I applied for a **10 year visitor visa** since my brother is a UK citizen and I don't want to apply every time. I have previously applied 3 times for a 1 year visa and always heard back within 15 working days. Could the duration have anything to do with the delay in processing?
3. Short of withdrawing my application and asking them to return the passports (I am guessing I can do that) and applying for an expensive premium service, do I have any options? I think not.

Any insight/experience is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `Could the duration have anything to do with the delay in processing?` Nobody can tell. You are **extremely** unlikely to get the 10 year visa, even a 5 year visa might be a stretch. The British are now keep on monetizing the issuing of visas as much as possible and you don't fit the profile of someone to be granted a 10 year visa. `do I have any options` None.